# Can a specific filename be pre-selected in a File Dialog Box?

Tags: powershell

I have a situation in which I am creating a file open dialog box for the user to select a file.  In *most* cases, they will need to select the same file, but not necessarily all of the time.  In the interest of speeding up the process for the user, is it possible to pre-select the filename so they only have to hit Enter, but have the option of selecting a different filename if they wish?

Here's what I have so far:

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {   
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a property that will select the file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Don't know about powershell but I remember in old vb you could set a filter to be a specific file name if you wanted. I'm sure you could do that here as well. Not the same as what you wanted but similar. I think changing the filter would satisfy your request of simplicity

Comment: Just to see, I tried an AppActivate and a SendKeys in order to see if I could "fake" the selection, but never could get it to send to the dialog box correctly.  Sounds like the filter is the way to go.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I could think of was to change the filter to be that of the file. User would still have to select the file in order to hit enter but you would reduce the decision process to next to nothing.

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {   
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "The data file | file.csv|All files (*.*)| *.*"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}
```

[image: Selection]

Answer (score 0):

Yes,via... filename.

```
function Get-PowerShellFileName([string]$initialDirectory,[string]$initialFileName){[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "Powershell (*.ps1)| *.ps1|All files (*.*)| *.*"
    $OpenFileDialog.AddExtension = $True
    $OpenFileDialog.DefaultExt = 'ps1'
    $OpenFileDialog.FileName = $initialFileName
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() |  Out-Null
    return $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

Get-PowerShellFileName $env:USERPROFILE 'filename'
```